Built-in speakers are not detected. Bluetooth audio works
I just installed Ubuntu on my Windows 11 PC yesterday. I have both installed with fast startup disabled in Windows 11. I tried a bunch of stuff, none of them worked.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on "HP OMEN Transcend Gaming Laptop 14-fb0xxx"
   Model - HP OMEN Transcend Gaming Laptop 14-fb0xxx
   Firmware Version - F.07
   OS Name - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
   OS Type - 64-bit
   Kernel Version - Linux 6.8.0-45-generic
   also lspci says my audio device is NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-broken.html.en   URL determines the correct page for you unstated system, so adjust so as to match your unstated Ubuntu product
